# Sync dialog shows some commits ahead, but git claims that remote branch is up to date

Tags: tortoisegit

When I open git sync dialog, it shows me that I'm ahead of 149 commits from origin/master.
However `git status`, `git pull origin master` and `git push` claims that everything is up to date and there is nothing to pull or push. What's more the remote branch looks like updated.

What does that information mean in that case and how to deal with it?

Comment: Try `git reset --hard origin/master`.

Comment: It resets my pointer to last commit before these 149 ones (2 months ago) and sync claims that everything is up to date. However when I then  ran `git pull`, it downloaded me again these commits from remote.

Comment: Which version of TortoiseGit are you using?

Comment: I finally found the source of problem. I created by accident a local branch named `origin/master`. Git keeps reference to it in _refs_ directory.
Additionally such branch isn't listed anywhere. Only `rev-parse` gave me information that something was wrong. TortoiseGit probably showed status based on the local reference of a accidiental branch. However `git status` had to use the correct branch.
All in all `git update-ref -d refs/origin/master` resolved my situation.